# Angular 2 default Rout not working

Tags: angular, express, angular2-routing

The default Rout of my Angular 4 app is not working.
Maybe there is a conflict with my express routes?

The wildcard route on the other hand is working not sure what is wrong.

my Angular routes:

```
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot([
   {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/validate',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'validate',
    component: ValidationComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/validate',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
],
  { enableTracing: true} // debugging

)...
```

I also configured a standard route in express:

```
app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: there should be used [`express static`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) for static files

Comment: remove `pathMatch: 'full'` from wildcard route.

Comment: I removed the  `pathMatch: 'full'` the wild crad still works but default still nothing. I have this line telling express were my files are `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));` is that ok?

Comment: Why you put slash here - `'/validate'` ? In my app I just use path for wildcard and default route as usual - without slash

Comment: I used the official document they have the slash https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my Problem maybe someone else will encounter this.

The angular cli framework generates a file: `app-routing.module.ts` which has a standard rout already, just use this file or remove it.